# RestKit: mapping array of key-value pairs to NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, restkit

Webservice sends me JSON that looks like that:

```
[
    {"key":"key1","value":"value1"},
    {"key":"key2","value":"value2"},
    {"key":"key3","value":"value3"}
]
```

How should I set up RestKit mapping to get the following NSDictionary?

```
@{ @"key1" : @"value1", @"key2" : @"value2", @"key3": @"value3" }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you, try this.

```
    NSDictionary *dict1 = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            NSArray *arr = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:<Parse the array here from RESTkit>];
            for (int i = 0;i < [arr count], i++)
            {
                NSDictionary *dict = [arr objectAtIndex:i];
                NSString *key = [dict objectForKey:@"key"];
                NSString *value = [dict objectForKey:@"value"];
                [dict1 setObject:value forKey:key];

            }

        NSLog(@" Dictionary %@", dict1);
[dict1 release];
```

Comment: Yes, of course I could do it manually. Just thought that maybe there is some other way.

Comment: @HiveHicks did you ever find a way to do this using mapping?